# How to know the valueChanged origin in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I created a custom element in `Aurelia` and I also have the `valueChanged`, however I need to do a certain action only when the `value` is changed outside of the custom element. Since the signature is `valueChanged(newValue, oldValue)`, how would I know when the value gets changed from the `ViewModel` and not from the custom element itself? Is that doable somehow with an `observer` or `observable`?

I actually got kind of a working sample, I saw that there's also an `__array_observer__` property when the `value` is changed from the `ViewModel`, and it works but it's probably not ideal. So I got this piece of code which kinda works

```
valueChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue !== oldValue && newValue.__array_observer__) {
    // value got changed outside of this custom element
  }
}
```

This is probably not ideal though, or is it? Any other suggestion in knowing where the `value` got changed outside of the custom element?

EDIT

As much as possible, I'm looking for a solution that will still have access to the custom element. Even if I want to get triggered by an external value change call, I still need to call an internal function of the same custom element.

EDIT #2

To give a little more description of my issue, I need to know when the `value` got changed from the outside because this will trigger an action that will re-affect the `value`. Without knowing if the change was from the outside of the custom element, I fall in a recursive call with no way to stop it. What I'm looking for is similar to what used to be the `caller` and the `callee` but this was removed with ES5 and Strict Mode, however this would have been very useful.

Still looking for an answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in gitter, you can use a suppress flag

```
value: number;
suppressValueChanged: boolean;
valueChanged(){
  if(this.suppressValueChanged){
    this.suppressValueChanged = false;
    this.logger.debug("the value has been changed from inside the element");
    return;
  }
  this.logger.debug("the value has been changed from outside the element");
  // here comes the code to run when the value is changed outside
}

internalSetValue(value: number){
  this.suppressValueChanged = true;
  this.value = value;
}
```

The reason I reset the flag in the `changed` method is that depending on the circumstances `valueChanged` can be called by Aurelia asynchronously so you cannot just do the following

```
  this.suppressValueChanged = true;
  this.value = 123;
  this.suppressValueChanged = false;
```

Sometimes, using a task will work

```
  this.taskQueue.queueTask(() => {
    this.suppressValueChanged = true;
    this.value = 123;
    this.suppressValueChanged = false;
  });
```

It really depends where exactly in Aurelia code you are changing the value. I've found that the first option gives the most consistent result.

Comment: Since I only care about the changes done from the outside of the element, I tried to inverse the logic but I don't have that much success with it yet.

Comment: Not sure why you need to invert it. Whenever you change the value from inside - call `internalSetValue` which will set the flag and eventually skip any code in `valueChanged` below the `return`.

Comment: I modified the answer to imply the usage

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it working with some changes to the value comparison. Your code helped a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a *CustomBindingBehavior* to intercept the `updateTarget` event. For instance:

```
export class InterceptBindingBehavior {
  bind(binding, scope, interceptor) {
    binding['originalUpdateTarget'] = binding['updateTarget'];
    binding.updateTarget = val => { 
      alert('property was changed outside of the element');
      //do something here
      binding['originalUpdateTarget'](val);   
    }
  }

  unbind(binding, scope) {
    binding.updateTarget = binding['originalUpdateTarget'];
    binding['originalUpdateTarget'] = null;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<template>
  <require from="./intercept-binding-behavior"></require>

  <some-element value.bind="message & intercept"></some-element>
</template>
```

Runnable example: https://gist.run/?id=bcd7d39ed94856caf586f224f89fd1ff

I haven't tested this in many cases and I'm not sure if it's best way.

If you want to do the opposite (intercept when the property is changed from the element instead of the VM) just replace `updateTarget` for `updateSource`.

More info about *CustomBindingBehaviors* http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-binding-behaviors/8

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Fabio this is interesting way of doing it, however I might have forgot to mention in my question that I still need to be in custom element context. Your intercept is completely outside of the custom element context, however I still need to call some function directly on the custom element itself, meaning when this value is externally I will call an action on my custom element. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Basically could I do everything within the custom element or do I really need to have an external binding behavior?

Comment: I think my answer only applies to BindingBehaviors. But, there's a workaround that could be done with custom-elements. I'll try to post and example here

Comment: I tried your `bindingBehavior` and this doesn't work if I try to put the `interceptor` inside the customElement template. I don't want to put it in the main app, it's just a layer that regular user shouldn't have to see or call when using my customElement.

Comment: I'm just now seeing this question. I think if you look at what @FabioLuz has done here and then what I did in my blog post you should be able to figure out how to accomplish this. https://aurelia.ninja/2017/07/16/getting-my-hands-dirty-with-aurelias-binding-engine-part-two/